# How to pull SAML Federation ID into a Formula Field?

Tags: formula, formula-field

One of my custom objects have a relationship with User object. I need to pull **SAML Federation ID** (Field Name: **FederationIdentifier**) of User object into a formula field in the custom object through this relationship, but it is not available in the **Insert Field** pick-list. Screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried just changing the API name in your formula field instead of declaratively inserting it? Like, just type in 'Current_User___C.FederationIdentifier__C' (assuming ofcourse that you have the relationship properly set.

Comment: @dotmiko: Yes, I tried that. As expected, check syntax yields "Error: Field FederationIdentifier does not exist. Check spelling."

Answer (score 4):

First create a shadow TextArea (long) (len =512) Federation Id field on User - `federationId__c`

Then ..

**Options**

1. Use Process Builder to set FederationId__c from Saml Federation Id in an update action that executes unconditionally. Unfortunately, SAML Federation ID isn't available to Workflow Field Updates - only Process Builder
2. Use a before insert/update trigger on User to do the same as #1

Then...

Use the shadow field in your cross object formula

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on Process Builder! I was about to use a trigger, but wanted to find if there is a way to solve this without a new db field.

Answer (score 1):

**SAML Federation ID in Reports**

This is not an answer to the question I asked. But in case you reached here, requiring SAML Federation ID of a related user only in a report, you do not have to create a new Formula Field. Instead, you could simply add it to your report type via a lookup. Instructions and screenshot below:

- Go to **Setup** > **Build** > **Create** > **Report Types**.
- Drill down on the Report Type that belongs to the object, in which you need to fetch the *SAML Federation Identifier* of related user.
- Click **Edit Layout**.
- On the right pane, choose your object in the **View** selector.
- Click the link that reads ***Add fields related via lookup >>***.
- Drill down on your user relationship field (in my case, it is "Current User") and choose SAML Federation ID. Click **Ok**.
- **Save** the Report Type.

You will now find SAML Federation ID in the list of fields available for you report. Cheers!

[image]